# Output the number of levels of all factors in a dataframe

Tags: r

I'm attempting to create a list or df that contains, for all factors within a data frame, the number of levels of the factor.

So, it appears I need to first identify the factors (using `is.factor()`) and then count the number of levels for each (using `length()`)

I was using `sapply`, but can't get what I am looking for.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
fac <- sapply(cf_nm, function(x) is.factor(x)  )
fac <- cf_nm[fac]
```

And I could simply count the levels here - but I was hoping for a more eloquent way of doing what I'd like.

Comment: please provide sample code you used

Comment: When you write "length of the factor" do you actually mean the number of factor levels?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `nlevels` not `length` for the number of levels.

Here is a quick solution.

```
sapply(df1[,sapply(df1, is.factor)], nlevels)
```